# Improving loading time via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, request, xmlhttprequest

I've got a simple question: would it make a website faster, if I use AJAX for new pages? Normally, every time my website is requested, the response will be a whole HTML document. But if I now run through a link and look into an other page of my website, everything will be reload. The header, the footer ... Although I only need some new meta data (title, description), dependencies like CSS and JS and the new article (=content). Everything else could stay and has no need to be reloaded. And reloading everything costs performance. Would it be faster only load an article via AJAX instead of the whole new document?

Darth Moon

Comment: If you're asking whether it's faster to transfer less data over a network connection than it is to transfer more data over a network connection, then the answer is yes.  As for whether or not your particular application has any other bottlenecks or whether there is an improvement in overall user experience by re-engineering the application in any way, we can't know.  But in general, yes, smaller amounts of data are smaller than larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of Course! If you load only an article instead of a entire HTML page, it will be more fast to user download.

An example in a ASP.NET page, you have various hidden controls, that make the page with very big data. In the project that I working now, every page has about 600 kb. But if I make a request, with the data in JSON, to load some text, it will be only 2kb of data.

Which is faster to download? 600kb or 2kb. Always prefer ajax to load only part of content.

Comment: Nicw to read. Thank you! There's only one more question: Are I'm also able to change the meta tags in the head? Like descriptions and titles?

Comment: @DarthMoon Yes. I know how do this with jQuery: $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", result.title);
With pure javascript would have some way too.